# How to get a response with new line characters with Django Rest Framework's Response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to understand how to use the Response class from DRF.
Using Django's HttpResponse, and using the following code:

```
return HttpResponse("Hello \n World", content_type="text/plain")
```

I get the following response:

```
Hello 
 World
```

Which is what I am expecting. 
However, using the following code: 
`return Response("Hello \n World", content_type="text/plain")` 
I get the following response:

```
"Hello \n World"
```

Notice how I also get the pair or quotes in the second one "". Since Response is a child of HttpResponse, how can I have the same result using Response?
I've come to this problem because I want to present new line characters and tab characters with Response, but I have not been successful so far.

The only the I've seen that might help me was using Renderers from DRF, and making a custom one for plain text. but I do not understand how to apply them to Responses, and I am a bit surprised that DRF doesn't support plain text considering it is a subclass of HttpResponse. Thank you

Comment: Two times you wrote `I get the following response` and you provided response output. But you didn't provide any details on how you are reading this response. Please edit your question providing more details on how you are reading and printing this response - source code or web browser.